# How to use the library of Haskell

Tags: string

I am trying to seperate Strings with " ," with "intersperse". (Beginner in Haskell )
But my program refuses to compile , because I get the error "Not in scope intersperse"
Therefore I wrote import Data.Char at the top of my program , but the problem keeps refusing to compile.

```
 import Data.Char

 myShow :: String -> String
 myShow s = concat ["[", intersperse ',' s, "]"]
```

What to do ? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694097/haskell-compiler-error-not-in-scope

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
import Data.List
```

Because `intersperse` functoion is it's part.
So your programm going to look like

```
 import Data.Char
 import Data.List

 myShow :: String -> String
 myShow s = concat ["[", intersperse ',' s, "]"]
```